# ruby - rackup problems

Tags: ruby, rackup

I am trying to run rackup for running a ruby application. I am getting this error.

```
C:\Ali\Ruby\App>rackup -p  $PORT -o $IP
[2016-09-30 06:11:32] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-09-30 06:11:32] INFO  ruby 2.2.4 (2015-12-16) [i386-mingw32]
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb:232:in `getaddrinfo': getad
drinfo: The specified class was not found.  (SocketError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb:232:in `foreac
h'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb:459:in `tcp_se
rver_sockets'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/utils.rb:70:in `
create_listeners'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:133:in
 `listen'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:114:in
 `initialize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:45
:in `initialize'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib
/rack/handler/webrick.rb:31:in `new'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib
/rack/handler/webrick.rb:31:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib
/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib
/rack/server.rb:147:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/bin
/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
```

What is wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from your command-line path, you're using MS-DOS.  The variables `$PATH` and `$IP` are Unix-style variables.  Under MS-DOS, you would use `%PATH%` and `%IP%`.

Try:

```
C:\Ali\Ruby\App> echo %PATH%
```

and if that works (displays a long path), try making those changes.

Comment: @sadegh: You have to SET the variables first before you can reference them.